# Wake On lan to pc with raspberry pi over ethernet

Tags: ethernet, wake-on-lan

I just want to use my rpi as a wake on lan packet sender. Because I can't Connect my computer directly to the router. So I want to use my raspberry pi as a bridge.My pc is connected by Ethernet to the raspberry that way the raspberry is connected to the internet and gives It to my pc and that way I can set wol packages without being connected to the router I Hope is  clear?

Comment: Why can't you connect your computer directly to your router?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very clear and this Rpi project is exactly what you're looking for http://www.jeremyblum.com/2013/07/14/rpi-wol-server/

Comment: I came across your answer in a review queue. It follows the model of a lot of spam the site receives. I was going to flag it and then I saw you have a long history on the site.  Please see the guidance [*here*](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) for recommending software.  Key points: replace your text with **why** this is what the OP is looking for, what it is, what it does, what makes it a better solution than a random Google hit, and the gist of how to use it to solve the problem.  Just a product link is really more appropriate as a comment.